# Style usercontrol child by name in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I saw the following code in stackoverflow:

```
   <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1"
                 x:Name="Uc1"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=Uc1, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </Style>
        </UserControl.Resources>

        <Grid>            
            <Label Content="Label 1"/>
            <Label Content="Label 2"/>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

**Question:** I now wonder if I can target a specific label inside my usercontrol.resources for styling. Is it possible inside my userControl? If so then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Style without a `Key` will be applied to all instances of the Target Type within the scope.

Give the style a `Key`, like,

```
<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="MyLabel">
```

and then use the Key as following

```
<Label Content="Label 1" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel}" />

<!--Will not apply the style to Label 2-->
<Label Content="Label 2"/>
```

**Edit:**

I read your question again, seems you want to reference a `Target` from a `Style`, not reference a `Style` from a `Target`. Is that right? It sounds *unnatural*, it is like wanting to know the name of an instance of a derived class, from the base class.

Comment: Accepted your answer : )